# Angularjs custom directive ngShow doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I think that I'm having scope problems that I'm not able to fix, here is an explanation of my problem.

I want to create my own directive "my-create-content" to insert an "img" HTML template in the element where the directive had been defined. Then, I've defined ng-show in "img" and a timeout that evaluates ng-show to false, but after timeout "img" element is no hidden. I'm not sur if it's a scope problem because ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" it's evaluated correctly.

Here's my code:

```
.directive('myCreateContent', [function() {

function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  scope.showImg = false;

  function updateImg(url){
    scope.imageUrl = url;
    scope.showImg = true;
  }

  if (scope.grid[0].image){
    updateImg(scope.grid[0].imageUrl);
    setTimeout(function(){
      scope.showImg = false;
    }, scope.grid[0].duration);
  }

}

return {
  scope: {
    grid: '='
  },
  template: '<img ng-show="showImg" ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" class="grid">',
  link: link
};
}]);
```

And the HTML:

```
<div my-create-content grid="grid" class="container">
```

Comment: did you loaded the javascript in the html?

Comment: Inject and use `$timeout` in place of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$apply` for AngularJS to understand scope variables have changed.

In this case, instead of using `setTimeout`, you should use `$timeout` which will take care of everything for you.

Read more here: [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$timeout`, because it's ensure that it's gonna be digested and thus rendered.

You could also use `$apply` inside the setTimeout, but it's not the best option because you could trigger some javascript error if AngularJS is already digesting

I put your code on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g07stzdk/3/

Reading your code, I think you are working on a carousel. If this is correct, the right function ub your code would be: `$interval` which is the equivalent of `setInterval` in plain javascript